# ¿Cómo crear un archivo que almacene los atributos de un objeto?

Tags: java, pascal

Existe algún identificador reservado como FILE OF de pascal en java, para crear archivos de una estructura.

Comment: ha que te refieres con crear archivos de  una estructura? si te refieres a los Records que se usan en pascal en java no existe tal estrucutra lo que en java se tiene solo simplemente clases que claro  tambien se pueden serializar para escribirse dentro de un archivo binario.

Comment: te dejo una link sobre un tutorial que seguro te servira https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-write-java-object-to-a-file/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En `java.io` encuentras todo lo necesario para escribir a un archivo de texto.
ejemplo:

```java
ClaseEstructura estructura;
OutputStream os = null;
ObjectOutputStream objos = null;
os = new FileOutputStream("estructura.txt");
objos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
objos.writeObject(estructura);
objOps.flush();
```